# using revealling moduler pattern for complex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modular

I have a very complex class so i decided to break into sub modules and trying to use revealing modules pattern.
 I have main class and decided to divide into smaller container function. but in current scenario

But i am not able to access any internal function from outside i.e  callSearchResultWithCallBack using searchFinder.Search.callSearchResultWithCallBack(). which pattern should i use to keep this code clean as well have control to call internal function in sub module.

Thanks

```js
var searchFinder;

function SearchFinder() {

  me = this;

  this.searchResult = null;

  this.init = function() {

    declareControls();
    createAccordian();
    addEvents();
    fillControls();

    var declareControls = function() {


      this.SearchButtons = jQuery('.doSearch');
      this.InputLocation = jQuery('#inputLocation');
      this.InputDistanceWithIn = jQuery('#inputDistanceWithIn');
      this.InputName = jQuery('#inputName');

    }
    var addEvents = function() {

      me.SearchButtons.click(function() {
        me.Search();
      });
    }
    var fillControls = function() {

      var getGetCategory = function() {


      }




    }

  }



  this.Search = function() {

    var url = '';
    var searchCriteria = {};
    validateAndCreateCriteria();
    callSearchResultWithCallBack();

    function validateAndCreateCriteria() {





      function validateAandGetCategory() {

        if (SearchValidation.ValidateZipCode(me.InputLocation.val().trim())) {
          searchCriteria.location = me.InputLocation.val().trim();

        } else if (SearchValidation.ValidateCityState(me.InputLocation.val().trim())) {
          searchCriteria.location = me.InputLocation.val().trim();
        }
      }


    }

    // need to access it outsite

    function callSearchResultWithCallBack() {

      me.searchResult(searchCriteria, SearchResultCallBack);


      function SearchResultCallBack() {

      }

    }



  }

}

jQuery(function() {
  searchFinder = new SearchFinder();
  searchFinder.init();
  searchFinder.Search.callSearchResultWithCallBack();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has multiple issues, first I will address the fact that for example `declareControls` is not executing. First declare the function than execute!

```
this.init = function() {

    var declareControls = function() {


      this.SearchButtons = jQuery('.doSearch');
      this.InputLocation = jQuery('#inputLocation');
      this.InputDistanceWithIn = jQuery('#inputDistanceWithIn');
      this.InputName = jQuery('#inputName');

    }
    var addEvents = function() {

      this.SearchButtons.click(function() {
        me.Search();
      });
    }
    var fillControls = function() {

      var getGetCategory = function() {


      }




    }
    declareControls();
    //createAccordian(); //not defined
    addEvents();
    fillControls();
}
```

Now let's look at others problems that will arise.

the `me` object referring to this is in the scope of `searchFinder` and does not refer to the same `this` in the instance of searchFinder.

---

function `jQuery` can be replaced by the commonly used `$`.

`searchFinder.Search.callSearchResultWithCallBack()` this is never going to work. Since the `Search` function is an object and `callSearchResultWithCallBack` isn't a property of this function.

Solution; make it part of the prototype of Search.

Steps:

1. Move `callSearchResultWithCallBack` outside the search function.
2. Add prototype to Search function
3. Call function via prototype.

```js
function callSearchResultWithCallBack() {

  me.searchResult(searchCriteria, SearchResultCallBack);


  function SearchResultCallBack() {

  }

}

this.Search.prototype.callSearchResultWithCallBack = callSearchResultWithCallBack;
```

If you want to fire this function outside of search use this:

```
searchFinder.Search.prototype.callSearchResultWithCallBack();
```

Please remember that `callSearchResultWithCallBack` will throw an error because `searchCriteria` is undefined.

---

This fixes your problems for now, but this code has to be revised thoroughly. But this should get you started. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/